# Get facebook video ID from url

Tags: php, facebook, url, facebook-graph-api

How to get facebook video *[ID]* from url such as:

```
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=[ID]
```

OR

```
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=[ID]&type=2&theater
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up PHP Documentation for `parse_str` and `parse_url` functions.

```
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=[ID]&type=2&theater';
parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $params ); 
// $params['v'] will hold the [ID] you need.
```